# HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8 raid swap

Tags: windows, raid, hp

We have a HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8 which boots vmware and loads 3 windows virtual servers. We started getting cyclic redundancy erros during backup and then one of the raid drives started showing red on it's push button release. I ordered a new drive and hot swapped it this morning. The new drive appears to be acting the same as the old drive. I tried to download a gui to see the raid status but everything I have tried says it will not run in virtual machine. I am afraid to power the machine down as I have read here that doing so could lose the array. Is there a way to tell if it is rebuilding?

thanks
mlc

Comment: Assuming VMware was installed using an HPE customized image (it probably was), you should have the Smart Storage Admin CLI utility available at the ESXi host level.  That will give you all the information and commands available from a GUI in CLI form.

Comment: The RAID status should also show up in iLO, but that may be limited in Gen8.

Answer (score 0):

You can (generally speaking) not access local hardware from within a virtual machine. The "only" job of a hypervisor ist total separation from the host's hardware. So you *will* have to use hardware tools (for example HPE's Smart Storage Administrator) directly on your host.

You can boot the DL380 directly into one (booting from a Support Pack ISO through iLO or USB) without any installation or download it for your specific hypervisor and install it there.

> I am afraid to power the machine down as I have read here that doing so could lose the array.

From your description this is unlikely, however just make a backup copy of your VMs before rebooting the host.